# Change the default calendar event duration in evolution

Tags: evolution, calendar

In evolution calendar, Month view, double clicking a day creates a new event. That event, by default, starts at 9:00 and ends at 9:25.

I don’t mind it starting at 9:00, but I would like to change the default duration to, say, 30 minutes: 25 minutes is a bit too short (and a surprising choice for a default duration!).

Comment: Have you tried any possible solutions so far?

Comment: Looked in evolution settings. Searched the internet. Ran `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.evolution.calendar`. Nothing.